# Bootstrap popover for all elements in a column?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm dynamically generating a table via an ajax call and I'd like all the elements in a particular column to show a popover on hover.  I have the following code in the success event:

```
strBtn1 = '<span data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="testing popovers in a table" class="test22">test</span>'
$('#myReport').append('<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>' + strBtn1 + '</td></tr>');
```

Then I tried this in my main script:

```
$(".test22").each(function () {
    $(this).popover();
});
```

The table is generated as I expect, with 15 rows, but hovering over the "test" text does nothing.

I also have a "control" of sorts that does work:

```
<span id="test11" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="testing popovers in a table">test</span>
```

That's directly in the HTML file in the header and this is in the main script:

```
$("#test11").popover();
```

So in the header I get a "test" that DOES show a popover when I hover.

Ideas?

Comment: So I just figured out WHY it's doing it, duh... it's never processing the "each" statement because the elements don't exist in the DOM yet...

Now to figure out HOW to fix it :)

Comment: wrap this with document ready handler

Comment: It was.  Answer posted below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this in the success fixed the issue.

```
counter += 1;
tmpID = 'thisCell' + counter;
strBtn1 = '<span id="' + tmpID + '" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="testing popovers in a table" class="test22">test</span>'
$('#myReport').append('<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>' + strBtn1 + '</td></tr>');
$('#' + tmpID).popover();
```

Then I deleted the "each" statement completely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that 
`$(".test22").each(function () {
    $(this).popover();
});` is running only *after* the table has been populated, otherwise it won't be able to find any of the classes.

To test to see if it is working, try putting a console log inside of the each function to see how many times the function is actually being executed.

If you do not get any console logs back, then that means you must be trying to run the each before there is anything to iterate through.

If that is indeed the case, then I recommend putting that jQuery each into a function and then calling that function in the ajax success.